# Why is height different on <ul> <li> and <a> elements on this example?

Tags: html, css, height

Why is height different on `<ul>` `<li>` and `<a>` elements on this example?

http://codepen.io/MonoSM/pen/mPGVrN

HTML

```
<ul class="links">
  <li class="first">
    <a href="#">My Account</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">My Cart (3 items)</a>
  </li>
  <li class=" last">
    <a href="#">Log In</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.links { list-style: none; }
.links li { float: right; display: inline-block; }
.links li a { background: grey; margin:5px; padding: 10px; }
```

[You can see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRc1t.jpg)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. What do you expect the heights to be?

Comment: I expect '<ul>' and '<li>' height to be the same as '<a>', but they are smaller

Answer (score 0):

The ul element contains only elements that have been removed from normal flow, so its height is 0.

Each li element contains one line box. It's height is the height of that line box, using its line-height property.

Each a element is the height of its text content. Taken from the font metrics. Vertical padding is placed around them, but do not affect their ancestors' parent heights because the a elements are `display:inline`

Comment: Many thanks, but how should it be styled so the heights would be the same. I added `display:block;` to `<a>` and now `<li>` are properly strehed, but still issues with `<ul>`